# Install a wordpress in localhost through node.js

Tags: wordpress, node.js

I am very new to node.js.
Now I want to install a wordpress in localhost through node.js. Now i just want to access that site through browser like i can serve using wamp.I have create a module and install the node-wordpress module.But now how can i view the site in browser ?

Comment: y node, if  you are using wordpress?

Comment: yes. But i just curious to know how i can run a wordpress using node.js without the help of wamp, nginx etc.

Comment: I want to use wordpress for frontend for my portal, but all asynchronous work to do with node.js and reading some data from wordpress mysql and writing some to mySql. Can someone please help me with steps how to achive this for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your problem is but if it's finding the site on your own browser.

you should be able to access sites hosted on your own computer by using the loop back address "127.0.0.1"

if you are not using the normal port for websites you can go to a port number by adding ":num" to the address for example if you are using port 2995 the address would be "127.0.0.1:2995"

you can also use the word "localhost" in most browsers in place of "127.0.0.1".

you must also start node before going to the page if you have not done so.

if you need more help with node you may find reading this helpful.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/node-js-for-beginners/

Comment: ok i understand But I just want to browse the wordpress site through node just like i use wamp as a platform to create web application  Apache2, PHP and a MySQL database. Plz help me...